# How to subplot2grid sharex

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I have read the questions and answers on how to use subplot2grid with sharex, sharey axes.  For some reason, ax.set_xlim is being ignored.   I am making five plots, populating the first five positions in a 3 x 2 subplot array.  For the first plot, I define the x and y limits:

```
ax1.set_xlim([1.0, 2.3]) 
ax1.set_ylim([-40, 140])
```

For the second plot, I use sharex and sharey to use the ax1.set_xlim and ax1.set_ylim.  When I run the code in interactive, console mode and only plot the first plot, the defined x and y limits are used.  Next, for the second plot, use sharex and sharey:

```
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (0,1), sharex = ax1, sharey = ax1)
```

At this point, when I check

```
ax2.get_xlim()
(1.0, 2.3)
ax2.get_ylim()
(-40, 140)
```

the limits match

```
ax1.set_xlim([1.0, 2.3]) 
ax1.set_ylim([-40, 140])
```

But on executing the next line of code for the second plot,

```
ax2.plot(x2,y, 'bo', label='Sensor 2')
```

xlim is different:

```
ax2.get_xlim()
(1.2, 2.2)
```

and not

```
(1.0, 2.3)
```

If I run the code as a script, then both plots use the undesired xlim of 1.2, 2.2
Here is the code for the first two plots:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress
x1 = np.array([1.592, 1.647, 1.699, 1.752,  1.793,  1.846,  1.900,  1.952,  2.033,  2.064,  2.113,  2.061,  2.008,  1.955,  1.906,  1.862,  1.808,  1.754,  1.701,  1.647,  1.594,  1.538,  1.482,  1.426,  1.373,  1.320,  1.266,  1.225,  1.267,  1.322,  1.376,  1.429,  1.487,  1.542])
x2 = np.array([1.617, 1.674, 1.726, 1.780,  1.822,  1.875,  1.929,  1.983,  2.036,  2.090,  2.143,  2.090,  2.037,  1.983,  1.933,  1.888,  1.833,  1.780,  1.726,  1.671,  1.617,  1.560,  1.503,  1.446,  1.391,  1.336,  1.282,  1.240,  1.282,  1.337,  1.392,  1.445,  1.502,  1.559])
y = np.array([32.12, 42.32, 51.83,  61.65,  69.10,  78.85,  88.51,  98.37,  108.13, 117.93, 127.68, 118.04, 108.32, 98.48,  89.45,  81.19,  71.40, 61.65,   51.86,  41.92,  32.23,  21.98,  11.66,  1.46,   -8.34,  -18.06, -27.78, -35.09, -27.79, -17.89, -8.29,  1.29,   11.43,  21.76])

# first plot
m, b=np.polyfit(x1,y,1) #x1 and y are 34 element vectors
ax1 = plt.gca()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (0,0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (0,1), sharex = ax1, sharey = ax1)
ax1.plot(x1,y, 'bo', label='Sensor 1')
ax1.set_xlim([1, 2.3])
ax1.set_ylim([-40, 140])
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.set_title('Sensor 1')
ax1.plot(x1,m*x1+b,'b-')

# second plot 
m, b=np.polyfit(x2,y,1)
#if ax2 is defined in this code section, (commented out), then a default ax
#is defined and overides ax1.set.lim and ax1.set.lim in code above
#ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (0,1), sharex = ax1, sharey = ax1)
ax2.plot(x2,y, 'bo', label='Sensor 2')
ax2.grid(True)
ax2.set_title('Sensor 2')
ax2.plot(x2,m*x2+b,'b-')
plt.show()
```

Not sure what I am missing.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: your example doesn't run. what are `x1` and `y`?

Comment: Paul H, x1=1.580135
1.635767
1.688523
1.741952
1.783195
1.836137
1.888842
1.942127
1.994955
2.047983
2.100443
2.047857
1.994868
1.941723
1.891825
1.847512
1.793985
1.741113
1.687737
1.633317
1.579850
1.523900
1.468182
1.412923
1.359358
1.305720
1.252248
1.211448
1.252418
1.306873
1.360053
1.412742
1.467693
1.523340

Comment: Paul H, y=32.12
42.32
51.83
61.65
69.10
78.85
88.51
98.37
108.13
117.93
127.68
118.04
108.32
98.48
89.45
81.19
71.40
61.65
51.86
41.92
32.23
21.98
11.66
1.46
-8.34
-18.06
-27.78
-35.09
-27.79
-17.89
-8.29
1.29
11.43
21.76, x2=1.5685
1.6240
1.6763
1.7295
1.7705
1.8230
1.8755
1.9285
1.9809
2.0337
2.0860
2.0338
1.9810
1.9284
1.8788
1.8347
1.7814
1.7289
1.6758
1.6218
1.5684
1.5129
1.4569
1.4018
1.3484
1.2948
1.2414
1.2004
1.2411
1.2954
1.3483
1.4007
1.4553
1.5107

Comment: Paul H, in the code for the second plot, the argument for polyfit should be x2 and not x1.  Just a typo and not relevant to my question

Comment: Use the *edit* button to include all of the information in your question that is required to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When ax2 definition directly follows ax1 definition, then sharex and sharey work for ax2:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (0,0))
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,2), (0,1), sharex = ax1, sharey = ax1)
```